# Sort mode selector is broken for questions when tagged mode is on

Tags: bug, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open questions
2. Tap for tune sort mode
3. Select some tags
4. Scroll sort mode carousel

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)